# put facebook login data into textfields with angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm implementing facebook login and its working alright with angular.but the problem is when i get the data from facebook i'm unable to put in a textfield. when i put it in an alert its able to give me the data but can't put it in a textfield.

```
 <div  ng-controller="facebook_login">
            <p align="center"><button class="icon icon-left ion-social-facebook button button-positive button-small"  ng-click="fbLogin()">Sign Up with Facebook</button></p>
            <div class="list">
                <div class="item">
                    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Fashion Line</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="email" ng-value="{{data.email}}" />
         <div>
```

JS

```
.controller('facebook_login',['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$timeout', 'ngFB', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, ngFB) {
 $scope.fbLogin = function () {
    ngFB.login({scope: 'email,public_profile,publish_actions'}).then(
        function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //alert('Facebook login succeeded, got access token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
                //$scope.closeLogin();
                 ngFB.api({
                 path: '/me',
                 params: {fields: 'first_name,last_name,gender,email,picture'}
                 }).then(
                 function (data) {
            $scope.facebook = data;
            alert(data.email)
            $scope.email = $scope.data.email;
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = data.email;
       });
            } else {
                alert('Facebook login failed');
            }
        });
};

}])
```

Comment: Try this: `$scope.email = data.email;`

Comment: yeah thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you never defined `$scope.data` but you're trying to use it. Did you mean `$scope.facebook.email` instead?